# What is the best method for importing from excel to sql

Tags: sql-server, import-from-excel

What is the best method for importing from excel to a table already set up in Sql(with column names,data types and Pk) in sql.

I have an excel table that can hold up to 30,000 records. I am using copy and paste to import atm. I have tried using the wizard but it is very erratic to use. It sometimes sets up duplicate tables and sometimes prevents the update completely so i gave up on using it.

Im aware that there are Openrowset,Bulk Import,Opendatsource and linked server options but I dont understand how to configure them.

I am considering using a Merge statement. Ive searched numerous posts here and havent seen a concrete answer as to what is the best method.

Can someone advise.

Thank you.

I forgot to ask what would **also** be the best method for updating data that needed to be updated in real time in Sql as soon as it was entered in excel.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "best". 30,000 rows is small enough that just about any method is going to be just fine under most circumstances. For a one time dump, i'd use the import export wizard. If I need to run it repeatedly, I'd use an SSIS package. These two would be my personal choices for this kind of work. Bulk insert using BCP is nice and quick, but as you say, it takes some understanding of the tool to configure.

Comment: By best I mean accuracy and speed.